# Адаптивность разметки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Пытаюсь сделать небольшой адаптивный интерфейс с помощью Bootstrap 4, но получается с трудом.

Есть страница, в которой две колонки при широком экране и одна при узком. У колонок есть содержимое переменной высоты в зависимости от содержания.

[image: Слева при широком экране, а справа то, что должно получиться, если уменьшить экран]

Порядок блоков важен в каждом из разрешений.
Если делаю это [через колонки](https://www.codeply.com/p/eU88dvurla), то получаю то, что ниже. А хочется, чтобы блок 3 тоже поднимался.
[image: Результат через колонки]

Если пытаюсь сделать через d-flex, то колонок получается больше двух, а так быть не должно в итоге.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Может быть, простыми инструментами это не сделать.

Comment: Попробуйте рассмотреть этот вариант https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790378/css-flexbox-group-2-flex-items

Comment: BS4 для колонок использует Flex. Flex создан для выравнивания по одной оси. Для выравнивания по двум осям, используйте grid (css grid). Или можете скрывать /показывать нужные блоки на нужных разрешениях.